# Thunderbird does not preserve profile's language packs enabled status

Tags: scripts, thunderbird, language-support, locale

I need to access the same Thunderbird profile from both Windows and Ubuntu.

On Windows 7, it's Thunderbird version 38 (I think?) whereas the Ubuntu version is 44 (from the thunderbird-next PPA).

Now I have a little language/localization problem: The Ubuntu's system language is English, but the user account has a German locale. Windows is entirely German. I want the Thunderbird GUI to be German on both Windows and the German Ubuntu user account.

The caveat here is that Thunderbird for Windows does not use language plug-in packages but seems to come as installation with fixed localization, but Thunderbird for Linux uses those language packs.

Now whenever I access the profile from Windows, Thunderbird detects those language pack plug-ins, does not know what to do with them and just disables them. Going back to Ubuntu, the language pack is disabled and Thunderbird starts with the default English locale.

**How can I automatically enable the German language pack whenever I launch Thunderbird from the German Ubuntu account?**
I guess I would have to write a script that modifies the profile configuration and then starts Thunderbird, and set that as `Exec=` line of the German user's personal `thunderbird.desktop` file. But I have no idea how to modify the profile using a script.

**Edit:**

Here are the contents of `extensions.json` in the Thunderbird profile directory:

- after the language pack was manually enabled in Ubuntu: http://pastebin.com/3sh0evwh
- after the language pack was automatically disabled in Windows: http://pastebin.com/NLdL9wJq

Both times the file originally was written into a single line, I just formatted it using http://jsonformat.com for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

[How do I get German language back in Thunderbird?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165869/how-do-i-get-german-language-back-in-thunderbird)

I hacked it. Not elegant, but it worked for ensuring UK English works.