# How do I get a non-English spell checking in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, language-support

How do I get a non-English spell checking in Thunderbird? In my case it is just Danish (apart from English) I want to have working.

I am in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Following a solution at [How do I get German language back in Thunderbird?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165869/how-do-i-get-german-language-back-in-thunderbird), I have done `sudo aptitude install thunderbird-locale-da`. I have also installed the Danish Language Pack (with "Download more dictionaries...") - and the dictionary is enabled. I have restarted Thunderbird.

During spell checking, I still do not see the Danish language in the drop-down menu. I only see English versions.

And BTW, I cannot even disable spell checking (thus the email editor is filled with curly underlining).

Comment: Did you download the dictionary, as well, or just the language pack?

Comment: @StefanHamcke I have downloaded the .xpi file with Firefox and installed it with Firefox. I reckon that it will then be available for Thunderbird?

Comment: I just tested it, and it worked for me. I downloaded the file from https://addons.thunderbird.net/de/thunderbird/addon/dansk-ordbog/, then in thunderbird I went to *Extras > Add-Ons* where I clicked on the small gear icon and then on *Install add-on from file* and selected the downloaded file.

Comment: Note that I have the German interface in thunderbird, so the the menu entries may have different names. *Extras* is probably *Tools* or something. In the *Add-on* window, you have to click on *languages* to make the gear icon appear.

Comment: Is the `hunspell-da` package installed?

Comment: `sudo aptitude install hunspell-da` might have worked. At least I see the Danish dictionary in Thunderbird's interface now after `hunspell-da` installation.

Comment: Great! I think that's the easiest way to fix it on an Ubuntu system.